How to convert String System Object into a Byte System Array in powershell?
I would like to create a binary blob from a binary character string, in the same way as when reading in a binary blob from a file, into a buffer, using .NET file stream. Then I would like to read 2 bytes from a particular offset in blob.
I create a file like this:
echo "AAAABBBB" > .\zzblob.txt 
$bytes = "AAAABBBB`r`n"
$aa = [system.bitconverter]::touint16($bytes, 0)

# FAIL!

# Checking the type:
$bytes.GetType() | select Name, BaseType | ft -HideTableHeaders

# String System.Object

Now, doing the same using a stream buffer, we get something else.
$fp = ".\zzblob.txt"
$bf = (new-object byte[](256))
$sp = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fp, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
$sp.Length
$sp.Read($bf, 0, 256)
$sp.close()

$aa = [system.bitconverter]::touint16($bf, 2)   # ..AA
d2h $aa
# 0x4141  ## OK!

# Checking type:
$bf.GetType() | select Name, BaseType | ft -HideTableHeaders

# Byte[] System.Array

How can I convert a string from String System.Object to Byte[] System.Array?


You can not convert an arbitrary .NET string to bytes without choosing a specific character encoding that should be applied to it.

The reasons is that different character encodings use different byte representations of characters, notably with respect to the number of bytes required to encode a single characters, which can even vary from character to character, as is the case with
UTF-8.

Whoever must interpret the resulting byte array as a string again must then use the same encoding for de-coding.



If all the characters in a given string happen to fall into the 8-bit subrange of Unicode code points, i.e. the 256 characters occupying the Unicode code points from 0x0 to 0xFF (255) (in Unicode terms: U+0000 to U+00FF), you can use a shortcut, assuming that you want to use the Unicode code points as byte values:

Use [byte[]] [char[]] $string (or [byte[]] $string.ToCharArray()), as also shown in js2010's answer:
 $string = 'AAAABBBB'

 # Convert TO a byte array.
 $byteArray = [byte[]] [char[]] $string
 # OR:
 #    $byteArray = [byte[]] $string.ToCharArray()

 # Convert back FROM a byte array.
 [string]::new($byteArray) # [char[]] cast optional
 # OR, more PowerShell-idiomatically, but less efficiently:
 #    -join [char[]] $byteArray


Caveat:  Any character outside that range, i.e. one with a code point of U+0100 (256) or above, e.g. € (EURO SIGN, U+20AC), breaks this approach, because its code point is by definition too large to fit into a [byte] instance:
 # -> ERROR: 
 #   Cannot convert value "€" to type "System.Byte". 
 #   Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."
 [byte[]] [char[]] '€'




This approach is tantamount to choosing the fixed-width, single-byte ISO-88591 character encoding for the byte representation, because the 8-bit subrange of Unicode coincides with this encoding.

That is, the equivalents of the above operations are (note that in PowerShell (Core) 7 you can more simpy use [Text.Encoding]::Latin1 in lieu of [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591)):
 $string = 'AAAABBBB'

 # Convert TO a byte array.
 $byteArray = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes($string)    
 # Equivalent of:
 #    $byteArray = [byte[]] [char[]] $string

 # Convert back FROM a byte array.
 [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591).GetString($byteArray)
 # Equivalent of:
 #    [string]::new($byteArray)




As for writing the byte representations to a file:

If you have an in-memory byte representation, it is safest to write to and read from files as bytes rather than via a character encoding:
  $string = 'AAAABBBB'
  $byteArray = [byte[]] [char[]] $string

  # NOTE: Sadly, the syntax for requesting byte processing differs
  #       between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7
  #       (-Encoding Byte vs. -AsByteStream), so we construct an
  #       an edition-specific hashtable to be used for splatting below.
  $encodingArg = if ($IsCoreClr) { @{ AsByteStream = $true } } 
                 else            { @{ Encoding = 'Byte' } }

  # WRITE the byte array to a file.
  Set-Content blob.txt @encodingArg -Value $byteArray 

  # READ the byte array from a file, as such.
  # Note: -Raw -ReadCount 0 reads the entire file *at once* into
  #       a [byte[]] array.
  $byteArrayFromFile = 
    Get-Content blob.txt @encodingArg -Raw -ReadCount 0


Alternatively, in PowerShell (Core) 7, you can use -Encoding Latin1[1] with Set-Content and Get-Content to directly write and read 8-bit-Unicode range strings, but that doesn't work in Windows PowerShell, where you'd have to use .NET APIs directly.







[1] The ISO-88591 encoding that -Encoding Latin1 refers to is closely related to, but not identical to Windows-1252, so using the latter - which -Encoding Default may refer to in Windows PowerShell, depending on the system locale (e.g. on US-English and Western European machines) - is not an option.

Great and very useful multi-purpose answer! As I'm trying to mimic reading a binary file (exe, dll), I guess the encoding doesn't matter as it's read byte-by-byte, and checking the hex dump of the (fake) string on my UTF8 system, yields only the expected 0-255 range, so within safe use bounds. Are you aware of any performance differences between using [byte[]] [char[]] versus using [byte[]] $x.ToCharArray()? I would expect the byte/char cast would be slightly faster? (I'm not sure how to use the Measure-Command when needing to run multiple times and average.)

Glad to hear the answer helped, @not2qubit. As far as I can tell, there's no significant performance difference between the two, which you can verify as follows: $str = 'x' * 1e5; Time-Command @({ [byte[]] [char[]] $str }; { [byte[]] $str.ToCharArray() }) - repeated invocations show very similar performance, with either approach incidentally being slightly faster, unpredictably. You can download function Time-Command from this Gist to run these benchmarks.

BTW. I see there is some substantial and less understood execution caching going on there, and the 1st run always runs almost 10 times longer than then latter ones.

@not2qubit: Yes, performance measurements are never an exact science in PowerShell, do to various forms of caching an JITting.  Do you mean multiple runs with the default run count (15) each? In PowerShell 7, for me the subsequent runs are only about twice as fast as the first ones, whereas in Windows PowerShell there seems to be no speedup. Also, while the .ToCharArray() approach tends to be slightly faster during most runs, every once in a while it appears to be up to twice as fast - no idea why.

Convert to character array first.  Note that $bytes is 10 bytes or 80 bits long.
[byte[]][char[]]$bytes

65
65
65
65
66
66
66
66
13
10


Indeed simple, but how should I interpret this correctly? Is it correct to say that "I'm casting a string to a character array, which is then cast again to a byte array"? (What's the difference between a string and a character array?)

It looks like I found an answer just after posting this.
$bytes = "AAAABBBB`r`n"
$byt = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8).GetBytes($bytes)
$byt.GetType() | select Name, BaseType | ft -HideTableHeaders

# Byte[] System.Array

$bb = [system.bitconverter]::touint16($byt, 4)
d2h $bb
# 0x4242  ## OK!

However, I am not sure that using a system text encoding of UTF8 is correct use for a binary blob?

"I am not sure that using [...] UTF8 is correct [...]" - That depends entirely on the encoding used to produce the string. From where and how do you obtain the string value in the first place?

0x4242 is just 'BB'.

@MathiasR.Jessen I just wanted to simulate reading a file blob, by manually typing in a string. And to be able to pass anything to then be able to understand and use the [system.bitconverter].
